# Image from async task never shows

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-xml

I tried to implement an image async task I got from here:

http://schimpf.es/asynctask-for-image-download/

I then tried to execute it in my code like this:

```
ImageView im1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
ImageDownloadTask imageD = new ImageDownloadTask(im1);
imageD.execute(e.mediumLabel);
```

The image never loads....

My xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/beerTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle = "bold"
        android:padding="5dip"
        >
    </TextView>

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonBrewery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text="" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/beerDEscriptionTitle"
        android:textStyle = "bold"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Description"
        android:padding="5dip"
        ></TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/beerDescription"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:padding="5dip"

        ></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No surprise that didn't work. The field "url" in the ASyncTask is never set. In the ASyncTask change this line:

```
 InputStream in = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
```

To actually use the parameter sent in execute(String)... Something link this should work:

```
 InputStream in = new java.net.URL(params[0]).openStream();
```

Comment: You can also remove the field "url" as its unused

Answer (score 3):

Do yourself a favor and use Picasso: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 0):

The URL in that AsyncTask image loader class is never set anywhere, the image is never downloaded. Either set it in the constructor or in the params when calling execute(). I would look into using some other method of loading images.

Also, make sure you have the appropriate internet permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
```